# Does the original string count as a substring of itself?

Tags: string, substring, definitions

This is a strange question but is the whole string considered a substring of itself?
Ie: String "cheesecake" has a substring "cheesecake".

Comment: Why not? It is. Maybe the question can be asked at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology, what to consider a "substring".

Comment: I understand a string to be a substring of itself, unless you want a _proper substring_  (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring).

Answer (score 2):

A string is a substring of itself. Wikipedia says the same.

Also, if you consider "string" as an amalgamation of set of characters, by definition of set - every set is a subset of itself.

Hence the answer - YES.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring